# jquery-ui, Foundation, and Rails 3.1 not playing well together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, zurb-foundation

I have a Rails 3.1 app that uses the foundation-rails gem and the jquery-rails gem and everything seems to be working.  I tried to add the jquery-ui-rails gem to the mix and ran bundle install and everything looks good.  Here is the relevant part of my gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'foundation-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

Here is application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

Here is application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides

 *= require_tree . 
*/

/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */
```

I have a page that includes the following code:

```
    <ul id='sortable_list'>
      <% @list.items.each do |item| %>
        <li><%=item.name%></li>
      <%end%>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>

<script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable_list" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable_list" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

The list is not sortable when the page loads and I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  I'm at my wits end - help, please!

Comment: you've left out part of your application.css.

Comment: OK, I put in the whole application.css.

Comment: Call jQuery instead of $ and it will work. See another post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836843/trying-to-load-slick-carousel-into-foundation-6-5/53856287#53856287 where I link to Foundation forum and show an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the issue was the current version of Foundation (5.0.2).  The documentation says that its script tag should be placed right before the closing  tag.  I put my script_tag for application.js there and, apparently, jQuery likes to be loaded in the head.  So I moved `//= require foundation` out of application.js, moved `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` back to the head, and added `<%= javascript_include_tag "foundation" %>` by itself at the bottom of the document.  I figure this will work until they fix the bug in 5.0.2 that requires that it be loaded at the end of the body.