# Trying to load Slick Carousel into Foundation 6.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use slick carousel with Foundation 6.5 and can't seem to get it to work.

I put the basic HTMl Markup

```
<div class="slick-test">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

I added the js files to app.js, I changed from **import** to **require()** which seemed to fix an issue I was having with the slick script.

```
require('../../../node_modules/slick-carousel');
require('../../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick');
require('./slick-scripts');
```

In slick-scripts I put a basic script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slick-test').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

I'm still getting the following error

```
slick-scripts.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
  at Object../src/assets/js/slick-scripts.js (slick-scripts.js:1)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
  at Module../src/assets/js/app.js (app.js:18)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
  at Object.0 (app.js:24299)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
  at bootstrap:83
  at bootstrap:83
```

I thought these types of **$ is not defined** were if the script was loading before jquery? I believe with the require() script this would load after JQuery?

[Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Is there another way that I should format the script?

Here is a screenshot of the full app.js file in case I have something in the wrong place.

[app.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlbif.png)

Comment: You need to use jQuery instead of $, or namespace it; Foundation jQuery is called with "jQuery". More here: https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/53512-how-to-call-call-jquery-in-64. There are some workarounds, I'm not sure why it's this hard to use jQuery with Foundation.

Comment: Nathaniel, thank you so much. This solved my problem. Two methods I found that seem to work are the two-step method by charlyRoot in the post you mentioned, or by replacing $(document).ready(function() with jQuery(document).ready(function($). I'm new to Stack Overflow but I can't seem to mark your comment as correct do you need to post it as an answer?

Comment: Excellent! Yep I’ll post my comment as an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery instead of $, or namespace it; Foundation jQuery is called with "jQuery". More here: https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/53512-how-to-call-call-jquery-in-64. There are some workarounds included in that forum post that do the same thing.

One way is like this ([hat tip](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/)):

```
(function($) {

    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);

})( jQuery );
```